# why do we still need parent constructor when controller class extends a parent controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, inheritance

I'm a beginner in CodeIgniter and OOP. I was reading a page of CI tutorial [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/news_section.html). I found something that made a question in my mind.
Look at this code:

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }
```

I think if we made a class that extends CI_Controller, we assume it must have all methods and properties in its parent class (Although we can override them). So, why there is `parent::__construct();` in the code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`__construct()` is the constructor method of a class. It runs if you declare a new object instance from it. However, if a class implemented its own `__construct()`, PHP would only run the constructor of itself, not of its parent. For example:

```
<?php

class A {
  public function __construct() {
    echo "run A's constructor\n";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function __construct() {
    echo "run B's constructor\n";
  }
}

// only B's constructor is invoked
// show "run B's constructor\n" only
$obj = new B();

?>
```

In this case, if you need to run class A's constructor when $obj is declared, you'll need to use `parent::__construct()`:

```
<?php

class A {
  public function __construct() {
    echo "run A's constructor\n";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    echo "run B's constructor\n";
  }
}

// both constructors of A and B are invoked
// 1. show "run A's constructor\n"
// 2. show "run B's constructor\n"
$obj = new B();

?>
```

In CodeIgniter's case, that line runs the constructor in CI_Controller. That constructor method should have helped your controller codes in some way. And you'd just want it to do everythings for you.

Comment: Your b declaration is missing parent in extends

Comment: So do we need to do the same for other methods in new classes that have a similar method in the parent class and want use their parent features? or this is just for `__construct()` classes ?

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi It depends on the actual case. If you don't override the parent's method, you don't need to do `parent::some_method()`. Even if you do override parent's method, you don't have to. The pattern provide ways for you to reuse code and save time. It's not a restriction.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly from the Code Iginiter documentation:

> The reason this line is necessary is because your local constructor will be overriding the one in the parent controller class so we need to manually call it.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#constructors

Answer (score 2):

Extension used for all classes. 
__construct() used for that class that you use.

Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each newly-created object, so it is suitable for any initialization that the object may need before it is used.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the need of calling the parent constructor/method is a **code smell**, known as **Call super**. Besides the error-sensitivity (forgetting this call, you can get unexpected results), it's procedural instead of OOP. After all, the order of statements can lead to unexpected results too.

Read more here: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is being used via the keyword `extends`. The parent class could be setting some values when its constructor is being called. If the parent constructor is not called the values are not set and the child class will not get those values.

Example:

```
class Super {
    protected $a;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->a = 'Foo';
    }
}

class Child extends Super{
    protected $b = 'Bar';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $this->a;
    }
}

$x = new Child();
```

Here, the class `Child` would echo out nothing if the parent constructor was not called.

So in Codeigniter the parent class is probably setting some values that are of help to its children when you call its constructor and those values are only available to its children if the parent constructor is called.