# Codeigniter, why do I need CI_Controller's construct?(code below)

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor, parent

Why do I need to use the parent::__construct(); constructor, what does it have I need?

//CONTROLLER

```
class users_ctrl extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); //Why do I need  to include it?
        $this->load->model('select_model');
}
    public function index()
    {
        $data['user_list'] = $this->select_model->get_all_users();
        $this->load->view('show_users', $data);
    }
}
```

//MODEL

```
class select_model extends CI_Model{
   function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
}

  function get_all_users()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('students');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why do we still need parent constructor when controller class extends a parent controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063890/why-do-we-still-need-parent-constructor-when-controller-class-extends-a-parent-c)

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Comment: Calling the [CI_Controller parent](https://github.com/mattbryson/Codeigniter_Code_Complete/blob/master/system/core/CI_Controller.php#L93) assigns all the class objects that were instantiated by the bootstrap file (CodeIgniter.php) to local class variables so that CI can run as one big super object.... if you have your own constructor, and don't call the parent constructor, then this won't happen, and things are likely to start breaking (like discovering that `$this->load` isn't set, so `$this->load->model('select_model');` won't work)

Answer (score 0):

In your given examples, you are calling the `load` class that the base controller class loads. Without the parent's constructor, you would have to load an instance of it yourself.

As for your model, you would have to manually load your db object.

Remove it and you should get something like `called to undefined propery $class::load`

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter aside, it really is a basic fundamental of object-oriented programming.

If you make a class that extends another, and you declare a new constructor in the child class, the parent constructor will never run - since you've overridden it, and since CodeIgniter base controller does (most likely) a lot of things behind the scenes, if you do not run parent constructor, your controller most likely won't be injected in CI's container.

Comment: I get that the child constructor will override the parent's but what I dont get is what CodeIgniter does behind the scenes, without which I cant do a query nor a lot other things..I will try to ask in a another way, what would the `class users_ctrl extends CI_Controller` 's construct look like if I provided everything it has to have to make the query possible?

Comment: [It seems like the constructor injects the `load` property by using a global function `load_class()`.](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Controller.php#L78). Anyway, I don't think what you are trying to accomplish makes sense, why would you not want to extend the base controller if you are using CodeIgniter? It defeats the purpose of the framework itself.

Comment: @GiamPy, It is normal practice in CodeIgniter (CI) to extend CI_Controller. CI uses controllers to create an association between a file and URLs. A CI sight might have many different controllers all extending CI_Controller.

Comment: @john-thomas, To answer  your "ask another way" question - it would look like you copied and pasted code from the CI_Controller class constructor into the users_ctrl class constructor. This would certainly violate the concept of Don't Repeat Yourself.